# Adding custom style to BIRT elements text

Tags: javascript, birt

My question is related to Eclipse BIRT (any version). What I am looking at doing is having a report generated from information from my dataset, one of my columns (summary) has HTML tags in it, so I am displaying it using a dynamic text component.

The summary column however has various styles (in my specific case, H1-H6) that are much larger than I would like to allow within the text box.

Is there any way to specify the styles used by a specific text elements content? I've searched around and could not find much information other then to change my entire style.

One solution I found was to simply do a find/replace using javascript on the text and just remove the tags or make them smaller.

I'd really rather use something that does not change the original tags if possible, but just restyles it.

Comment: You should mention the emitter that you want to use. For the HTML emitter, it should be possible to wrap your dynamic text in a div or something with a class attribute, then use you could use CSS. For PDF output, however, I don't see a solution at hand.

Comment: I did not mention an emitter because generally the way the system is setup is to use multiple (I believe in this case, the output types are PDF, HTML, and Excel).

Answer (score 0):

I've never realy researched the style sheet behavior in BIRT, but in general (i.e. web development where css is at it's strongest) you could add a general class to the containing element and then use CSS descendant and children selectors to specify the style of cirtain elements in that class.

Take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp